# How to do a loop for data in python crawler

Tags: python, regex, for-loop

I can take out the first set of `<tr>` but how do i take out the next set of `<tr>`.

And how do i make the loop stop at the last set of `<tr>`?

```
x = 1
while True :
    next = re.search("\<tr>(.*?)</tr>" , match).group(0)
    print next
    x = x + 1
```

`match` in this case contains my crawled table information.

Comment: Use an HTML parser to parse HTML. Using regex for this is bad for your mental health.

Comment: cant use any html parser due to some other function that cant support the parser for now

Comment: That is *very* unclear comment. How can a HTML parser conflict with "some other function"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `search` method will only find the *first* match. You must use [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) instead of `search` to find all matches, such as:

```
matches = re.findall("\<tr>(.*?)</tr>" , my_html)
for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

That being said, using a specialized tool such as BeautifulSoup is probably a better bet for parsing HTML as @DisplayName mentioned.